# git hooks in Azure Data Studio

Tags: azure-data-studio, git

Is it possible to use git hooks in Azure Data Studio, for example to run a linter against my SQL code?

I can't find any description of it in the documentation. And I can't translate my Visual Studio Code workflow, as that involves the Python package `pre-commit`.